# v140 toolset fails to link within Windows Container volume

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio

Using the following Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Install Chocolatey
RUN powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

RUN choco install git openjdk11 7zip.install visualstudio2019buildtools -y
RUN choco install visualstudio2019-workload-vctools --package-parameters "--no-includeRecommended --includeOptional" -y

VOLUME C:\Users\build
WORKDIR C:\Users\build
```

And the following docker build and run commands within git bash:

```
cd docker/cpp-build && docker build -t cpp-build:latest . && cd ../..
export MY_BUILD=C:\\code\\build
winpty docker run --rm -it \
  -v ${MY_BUILD}:C:\\Users\\build \
  --name cpp-build-run \
  cpp-build
```

From within the container, I'm able to build a large VS C++ solution with the v142 and v141 toolsets, using:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat x64 -vcvars_ver=14.0 && cd src && %BUILDCMD%
```

Unfortunately, this is an in-source build, outputting to the same volume. But, this works flawlessly with "newer" VC++ toolsets. But, I also need to support the `v140` toolset. And, it just so happens that always fails to link with these errors in every project:

> fatal error C1041: cannot open program database '*.pdb'; if multiple
> CL.EXE write to the same .PDB file, please use /FS

I've tried several things:

1. Run the same exact `choco install` commands in a new Windows VM. And, the same step to build. Then, the `v140` toolset builds just fine.
2. Turn off antivirus
3. Increase Docker VM RAM with `%USERPROFILE%\.wslconfig`

Any ideas of what else to try? There is obviously some issue with the way I am mounting the source directory and the way the older VC++ toolset attempts to link pdb's there.

Comment: If you install SysInternals Process Explorer in your Docker container it can tell you if any process is holding the PDB file open.